# appropriate c# collection when doing calculations that look at consecutive values

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, linked-list

I have this list example where I want to iterate over the list in order and get the first week that has a value which is below a minimum supplied value (i.e. 10) and it's next 2 week values are also below the minimum OR at least one of it's next 2 week values is negative.

e.g. week "201303" has a value of 8, the next week "201304" (-3) is negative so regardless of "201305" (15) being above the minimum the result would be "201303".

If "201304"'s value was 3 then there would be no match and to return null.

```
        var weekList = new List<WeekData>() {
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201301", Value = 15},       // 31-12-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201302", Value = 12},       // 07-01-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201303", Value = 8},        // 14-01-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201304", Value = -3},       // 21-01-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201305", Value = 15},       // 28-01-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201306", Value = 12},       // 04-02-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201307", Value = 13},       // 11-02-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201308", Value = 8},        // 18-02-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201309", Value = 15},       // 25-02-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201310", Value = 15},       // 04-03-2013
            new WeekData {PlanningWeek = "201311", Value = 15}        // 11-03-2013         
        };

    public class WeekData
    {
        public string PlanningWeek { get; set; }
        // GetStartDate() being another custom extension method, used later
        public DateTime? WeekStartDate { get { return PlanningWeek.GetStartDate(); }}
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
```

What would be an appropriate collection for doing this? SortedList ? LinkedList ? List ? or something else?

The list is expected to contain a maximum of 13 items.

If someone has a nice example of achieving this then that would also be very helpful.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what kind of List or Enumerable is used. Just order and walk the data. It might be useful to use Take (take next N elements to use in comparison in each loop) and Skip (advance to the next start element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the number of items you will have is so small, you don't need to resort to hash-based structures for performance, and could settle for a `List<WeekData>` (as you're already doing).

Regarding your query, that might be easier to do using plain old loops rather than LINQ. Here's an example:

```
WeekData firstBelow10 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < weekList.Count - 2; ++i)
if (weekList[i] < 10 && (
        weekList[i + 1] < 10 &&
        weekList[i + 2] < 10 ||
        weekList[i + 1] <  0 ||
        weekList[i + 2] <  0))
    firstBelow10 = weekList[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendations if there is a lot more data in the collection?

Comment: @Pricey: That depends on the details of your scenario (such as the actual size of the collection, how many queries you need to run against it, and how often its content changes). If the collection is large enough to cause performance issues, then you're probably loading it from a database; in which case, the best approach would be to maintain indexes on the two columns, and issue queries directly to the DBMS.